# Flag of invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning, nilpotence

How can I prove that for a nilpotent endomorphism $\xi: V \to V$ with $\xi^k(V) = 0$ and $k$ being the smallest natural number to do so:

$$\{0\} = \xi^k(V) \subsetneq \xi^{k-1}(V) \subsetneq \dots \subsetneq \xi(V) \subsetneq V $$

and deduce from that fact that $k \leq n = dim(V)$? Intuitively, it is clear that less and less basis vectors are spanning the $\xi$-invariant spaces but I have no clue how to show that in a formally correct fashion. As soon as this is showed, the corrolary of $k \leq n$ is clear I think.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

For every $m$ the inclusion $\xi^{m+1}(V)\subset \xi ^m(V)$ is trivial. So it suffices to get the desired result to prove that
$$\xi^{m+1}(V)=\xi^m(V)\implies \xi^{p}(V)=\xi^m(V),\;\forall p\ge m$$
which is done  by induction using that $$\xi^{p+1}(V)=\xi(\xi^p(V))=\xi(\xi^m(V))=\xi^{m+1}(V)=\xi^m(V)$$

Comment: Great, thanks! What you mean with the inclusion $\xi^{m+1}(V) \subset \xi^m (V)$ is trivial, is that $Ker(\xi^{m}(V)) \subset Ker(\xi^{m+1}(V))$ but $Im(\xi^{m+1}(V)) \subset Im(\xi^{m}(V))$, right?